# How to implement multiple background-images for an id / class with the same CSS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

so I have a banner id for my website that goes like this for one of my pages

```
#photo-banner {
    background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
    background-color: #645862;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../images/banner3.jpg");
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto, cover;
    color: white;
    padding: 7em 4.5em 3em 4.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The id attributes to a  element in the HTML.

However, this only works for one page. If I wanted to make another page with a different background image with the same other settings, as far as I know, I would need to make another id for that.

I'm thinking there's a way with JS / jQuery to change out the background-image in the HTML file rather than the CSS file to save a lot of code writing.

Or if there's another more optimal way, I would greatly appreciate that too, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask]. Your question is unlikely to be answered because you haven't even tried to solve the problem yourself, and we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page two give the element a class and use this to override your current CSS. All the rest of your CSS can stay the same and will be re-used :

```
#photo-banner { /* this will apply to page 1 and page 2 */
    background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
    background-color: #645862;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../images/banner3.jpg");
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto, cover;
    color: white;
    padding: 7em 4.5em 3em 4.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

#photo-banner.page-two { /* this will apply to page two only */
   background-image: url(some-other-image.png), url(some-other-image.png");
}
```